# удаление слов и букв из середины предложения

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как удалить слова и буквы из середины? Вот пример:

```
<button data-bem="{&quot;button&quot;:{},&quot;z-calculator__btn&quot;:{&quot;action&quot;:&quot;ins&quot;,&quot;arg&quot;:&quot;7&quot;}}" role="button">кнопка</button>
```

Нужно, чтобы jquery удалял все что находится между ***data-bem="*** и ***" role="button"*** середина может быть разной *{"button":{},"z-calculator__btn":{"action":"ins","arg":"7"}}*

мне нужно только примерно как решить или методы или в каком направление искать, так как задача сложная, и просто нуждаюсь в векторе поиска решения проблемы.

Comment: какой конечный результат вы хотите? `<button data-bem= ... >` это строка или это html элемент?

Comment: Именно ваш комментарий и помог! мне как раз и нужно было из переменной брать и изменять, искренне вам спасибо!

Comment: @alex-lenk Сделал ответ из коментария

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если приведенное вами в виде строки в переменной и сам текст data-bem="" должен остаться, то:

```
 var a='<button data-bem="{&quot;but..." role="button">кнопка</button>';
 a.replace(/data-bem=".*?"/,'data-bem=""');
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно удалить что либо внутри атрибута некого тэга, используйте следующий метод

```
 $(selector).attr('atribute_name', 'atribute_value ')
```

И выйдет примерно что-то  такое

```
 $(selector).attr('data-bem' , '')
```

Comment: @tutankhamun, спасибо, исправил. Был с телефона, вилимо случайно добавил.